# Having trouble with my string. Error pops up saying "unexpected string"

Tags: javascript, string

```
var contacts = {
    'addressBook' : [
    {
        'name': 'hillisha'
        'email': 'hill@example.com',
    },
    {
        'name': 'neil'
        'email': 'neil@example.com',
    },
    {
        'name': 'brian'
        'email': 'brian@example.com',
    },
    {
        'name': 'matt'
        'email': 'matt@example.com',
    },
    {
        'name': 'mike'
        'email': 'mike@example.com',
    }

    ]
};
```

error pops up saying unexpected string.  Not sure why and need help.  I am trying to just run a rather simple loop and it isn't expecting string.

Comment: You have a comma after "email", but not after "name" - why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing your commas after each 'name' element on the objects inside the array. Note that that the last comma, after 'email', is actually optional.